# Jekyll - Liquid Exception: Unknown operator forloop

Tags: for-loop, jekyll, liquid

I've updated jekyll and now get this error:

```
Liquid Exception: Unknown operator forloop in collection.html
```

Here's the code in question:

```
{% for tag in site.content_data.tags %}{{ tag }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

How would I resolve this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suspect your `{% if not forloop.last %}` is not the valid syntax, as I don't see it in the [operators section](http://wiki.shopify.com/Logic).

Have you tried `{% if forloop.last == false %}`?

Comment: faced with exact same problem. the reason of error was that you can check if variable was passed into render doing like this {% if variable %}. And maybe this behaviour should be changed for better equability.

Answer (score 6):

Not to contradict Yi Zeng, but you can also solve this issue using:

```
{% unless forloop.last %}something{% endunless %}
```